Could be possible to change the visibility of some geometry in geometry nodes?
There is this option that allows some geometry to be hidden in the viewport

And I will like to do this to some geometry in a geometry node, but I can't find a node for this. So far the best thing I found I could do is to set it to a transparent material, but I still can see the geometry in Solid mode.
Is this possible?

you could have a master geo nodes setup, use a store attribute node and assign a value to the objects you want displayed differently.
On a second geonodes object, you can read the master node, separate geometry based on the stored attribute, then display that however you like with the settings you posted. you can use a second geo node object to display the other half and use different diaply settings. hope that makes since, if not i can post photos.

thank you, that is a good idea. but in my case I need the geometry to stay there, just not visible
